# Binding in ListBox using MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, listbox, uwp

I have a problem binding all array entries to my `ListBox` in XAML.

XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ResultFlag}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TypeInfo}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

`ResultFlag` property in my ViewModel (which is the `DataContext` of the XAML file):

```
private ObservableCollection<DataField> _resultFlag;
public ObservableCollection<DataField> ResultFlag
{
    get { return _resultFlag; }
    set
    {
         _resultFlag = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

`TypeInfo` in the `DataField` class:

```
public string[] TypeInfo { get; set; }
```

I would like to show all string entries from above array in the `ListBox` - how should I do this? I've tried several things including nested `Listbox` and binding the `ItemsSource` of the `ListBox` directly to the array (didn't work, BTW)
Cheers!

Comment: Bind your collection to the ItemSource property.... ListBox.ItemSource={Binding MyCollection}.  Why didn't I work? is there an error?

Comment: Wrote the wrong thing..  the collection containing the objects with the array property is indeed already binded to `ItemsSource`, edited my post.

Comment: So, just to clarify: No errors. It does work on one level, but its a list of arrays I want to visualize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have in your scenario is a List of List. In order to show that in your list box you need to have nested ListBoxes like this.

```
       <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ResultFlag}" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding TypeInfo}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: Ya, I tried this, but it has some downsides:  
1. It doesn't look very good with a `ListBox` around `ListBox`'es    
2. How do I bind the `SelectedItem` og the nested `ListBox` to a property in my ViewModel?

Comment: If you are worried about the looks, then you can definitely change it by applying a style that you like. XAML is very efficient at that. What would you scenario be if `ResultFlag` which is an `ObservableCollection<DataField>` contains more an one `DataField`? Which `TypeInfo` from these `DataFields` inside your `ResultFlag` do you want to display inside your `ListBox`?

Comment: You just made me realize that something else must be wrong in the code, since this ´ObservableCollection<DataField>´ always will contain only one element in my case. I'll be back with update and upvote when I get my code straight!
Thanks for now.

Comment: Just needed to bind to a single element, so it was simply `xxxx.TypeInfo`. Thanks for putting my mind straight, marking as answer since it actually is.